# Application crash for row issue (tableView, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a viewController with a tableView. When the application runs it crashes by the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'

Rhis is part of the code of the viewController:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import Social
import AVFoundation

private let resueIdentifier = "MyTableViewCell"

extension UIViewController {
    func present(viewController : UIViewController, completion : (() -> ())? = nil ){
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            presented.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}

class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let minimumSpacing : CGFloat = 15 //CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = 250
    var category : QCategoryy?
    var places: [QPlace] = []
    var isLoading = false
    var response : QNearbyPlacesResponse?
    var rows = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = category?.name
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        determineMyCurrentLocation()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        rows = 0
        tableView.reloadData()
        insertRowsMode3()
        category?.markView()
    }

    @IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        rows = 0
        tableView.reloadData()
        insertRowsMode3()
    }

    func insertRowsMode2() {
        for i in 0..<places.count {
            insertRowMode2(ind: i, usr: places[i])
        }
    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,usr:QPlace) {
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
    }

    func insertRowsMode3() {
        rows = 0
        insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
    }

    func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

        guard ind < places.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {
            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  places.count    /*  rows   */
    }

    public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(place: place)

        if indexPath.row == places.count - 1 {
            loadPlaces(false)
        }

        return (cell)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        })

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: users[indexPath.row])
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            places.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
}
```

Adding a breakpoint I saw that the crash is in this func:

```
func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
    let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
    rows = ind + 1
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

    guard ind < places.count-1 else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {
        self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
    }
}
```

exactly at this line:

```
tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
```

I know that have to first update my `UITableViewDataSource` and then insert rows, but I don't know how and what I have to modify to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use begin & end update methods before and after your changes.

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
// your modifications to the tableView
tableView.endUpdates()
```

It tells the tableView to stop matching dataSource with actual tableView in this period.

Comment: so i have to add this in my func insertRows[2|3] ?

Comment: To describe in detail. after `beginUpdate` you start modifying your dataSource, inform tableView about rowChanges (insert, delete ... ) and then `endUpdate` commits all your modifications all together so nothing won't mismatch. So yeah, put it in those functions

Comment: @farzadshbfn can we use it for canEditRowAt as well ?

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed technically it should, but can edit is just a flag to let table know, this cell can be edited

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed I usually don't use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` in committing editingStyle methods or `SwipeAction` methods. But I do make sure to sync my dataStore with those commits.

Answer (score 0):

For each index path passed to `insertRows`, you need to add a corresponding object to your `places` array. The data model needs to be up-to-date before you tell the table view about any change in rows.

Note that in your `commit editingStyle` method you correctly update `places` before telling the table view to remove a row.

Your `insertRowsMode[2|3]` methods need to do the same thing except of course you need to add a value to `places`.